# Complex aggregations with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Supposing this is my elasticsearch structure:

```
 {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "person",
    "_id": "ID",
    "_source": {
       ...DATA...
    }
 }

  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "result",
    "_id": "ID",
    "_source": {
       "personID": "personID"
       "date": "timestamp",
       "result": "integer",
       "speciality": "categoryID"
    }
 }
```

I would like to get the most 10 most "influent" people based on:

- number of competition in the last 30 days
- number of competition in the last year
- competition's results in the last 30 days
- number of different specialities in the last 30 days

I'm thinking about using _score but I don't know how to influence the score using some values aggregated from the documents of type "result" . This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
POST my_index/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
 "size": 10,
 "query": {
  "function_score": {
   "query": { 
    "bool": {
     "must": [
      {
       "term": {
        "_type": {
         "value": "person"   
        }
       }
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  },
  "functions": [
   {
    "field_value_factor": {
     "field": {
      "query": {
       //competitions in the last 30 days
      },
      "aggs": { 
       //cout
      } 
     },
     "factor":   1
    },
    "weight": 0.1
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

1. Is this possible with just 1 request?
2. Is this a good approach?

   Any tip on what to look at is appreciated