# Query for : How many elements of an array are matching in a document attribute in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've many documents having an attribute that is an array of values like these:

```
{
   "_index": "myindex",
   "_type": "mytype",
   "_id": "myid1",
   "_source": {
      "tags": [
         "devid",
         "batman",
         "obama"
      ]
   }
},    
{
   "_index": "myindex",
   "_type": "mytype",
   "_id": "myid2",
   "_source": {
      "tags": [
         "devid",
         "superman"
      ]
   }
}
```

I have an array of elements like: `["devid", "batman", "pippo"]`

I want to get all the documents matching at least one element of the array, sorted by how many elements are matched.
For example, I expect that `myid1` will have an higher score than `myid2`.

How can I do this?

At the moment I'm "stuck" here:

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "tags": ["devid", "batman", "pippo"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It only filters by terms and sets 1 as score to both.

I'm **noob** with elasticsearch any hint is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) instead of filter would result in documents with more terms matching get a higher score.

Example :

```
   {
   "query": {
      "terms": {
         "tags": [
            "devid",
            "batman",
            "pippo"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yeah this is probably the solution. Gonna test and accept tomorrow.

Comment: PS: I've seen you have answered many elasticsearch questions. Do you have any tip on how to improve with it? Any course, online resource, ecc..
PPS: Am I the only one who think the online documentation is very complete but not very easy to use? 
Thanks again

Comment: Not sure if you have already come across this  but found the [definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/index.html)  helpful.

Comment: Yes, some month ago, I hoped for something more lightweight :) Thanks anyway.
If you want there's also this question about elasticsearch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702810/complex-aggregations-with-elastic-search